# Does D language have any "proprietary" baggage?

Tags: licensing, d, gnu

I'm looking at D's licensing and see that the frontend is open source but the backend is not; what is the backend?

Why did GNU make gdc? Is it related to licensing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different compilers with different goals. The frontend analyzes the source code, whereas the backend does the actual compilation. With the frontend being open-source, it can be used for multiple compilers.

**DMD** is the closed source default implementation of D. It is feature-complete, but may not be the best compiler performance-wise.

**GDC** uses the mature [GNU compiler collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) as backend. The same backend is widely used in C or C++ compilation and able of advanced optimization.

**LDC** targets the [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) platform. This allows some interesting stuff like high-speed compilation, portable bytecode, and jitting.

As the frontend is shared across all compilers, one source file will parse the same way on every compiler. Compare this to C or C++ dialects.

Answer (score 6):

DMD is just a reference implementation of the D compiler, just like, say, Glassfish is the reference implementation of the enterprise java application server.
DMD's backend has roots in DigitalMars C/C++ compiler. Makes sense as the original D creator is the the author of the DigitalMars C/C++ compiler, right? Walter could not legally completely open-source the backend because part of it has been made while it was in hands of Symantec...

Second, GNU *did not* make GDC - it was made by few enthusiasts, and hopefully will soon be merged into the GCC tree. GDC is GPL, simple as that.

LDC was also mentioned - it uses LLVM as backend.

What really matters is that D frontend is open-source. The fact that DMD's backend is not is irrelevant as there are so many alternatives. Both GCC and LLVM backends are superior to the DMD backend anyway.

If you are into compiler/interpreter design, I suggest you take a look at the SDC, MCI, and DIL projects. I think you have more information about them on http://wiki.dlang.org .

Comment: For what it's worth (a few months later), there is also a D for .NET compiler. [link](http://dnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I haven't heard any news about D.NET in years... Many people talk about it as dead project. Pity, it was an interesting project, IMHO.